# Execute php url with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possibe to simply load a php script with a url with js?

```
$(function() {

            $('form').submit(function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                var title = $('#title:input').val();
                var urlsStr = $("#links").val();
                var urls = urlsStr.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/[^\s]+/gi);
                var formData = {
                    "title": title,
                    "urls": urls
                }
                var jsonForm = JSON.stringify(formData);                

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    data: { jsonForm : jsonForm },
                    url: 'publishlinks/publish'                    
                 })

                 //load php script

            });

});
```

**Edit:**

```
 function index() {

            $this->load->model('NewsFeed_model');
            $data['queryMovies'] = $this->NewsFeed_model->getPublications();        
            $this->load->view('news_feed_view', $data);

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by load? What's wrong with AJAX?

Comment: What do you understand by *load a URL*? What do you expect to happen? What do you want to do?

Comment: @Felix Kling url of php script

Comment: @amiawizard: That does not all answer my questions and I already understood that. If you provide more information you will get better answers.

Comment: @Felix Kling I need to execute the script as I would with form submit, as this JS would execute if it didn't have e.preventDefault().

Comment: You execute a PHP script by requesting from a server to run the resource. Do you mean how do you trigger a form submission in the browser that points to your PHP page?

Comment: @amiawizard: And what is the current problem?

Comment: @Felix Kling 'news_feed_view' isn't loading

Comment: @FelixKling let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2466/discussion-between-amiawizard-and-felix-kling)

Comment: Felix tried to help on the last thread. The  "question" has been answered multiple times already, I think the OP is confused as to how server-side and client-side code behave.

Answer (score 3):

simple

jQuery and:

```
<script>
    $.get('myPHP.php', function(data) {});
</script>
```

Later edit:

for form use serialize:

```
<script>
    $.post("myPHP.php", $("#myFormID").serialize());
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that executes it? for me it's just sending a get request to the url.

Comment: as soon as the url is hit the code inside that url executes as PHP stands for Preprocesing HyperText ...

Comment: In the script I execute there is a view that is suppose to be loaded, why isn't it loading?

Comment: Sending a get request to a url causes the scripts in the url to execute.

Answer (score 1):

like this ?

```
$.get('myPHP.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to execute a server side page using jQuery. Every method has its own configuration and at the minimum you have to specify the url which you want to request.

**$.ajax**

```
$.ajax({
     type: "Get",//Since you just have to request the page
     url:"test.php",
     data: {},//In case you want to provide the data along with the request
     success: function(data){},//If you want to do something after the request is successfull
     failure: function(){}, //If you want to do something if the request fails
   });
```

**$.get**

```
 $.get("test.php");//Simplest one if you just dont care whether the call went through or not
```

**$.post**

```
var data = {};
$.post("test.php", data, function(data){});
```

You can get the form data as a json object as below

```
var data = $("formSelector").searialize();//This you can pass along with your request
```