# Execute php script with JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Execute php url with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057633/execute-php-url-with-js)

How can I simply execute a php script, is there a JS or jQuery function for this? Same behaviour as a form submit.

```
function index() {

      $this->load->model('NewsFeed_model');
      $data['queryMovies'] = $this->NewsFeed_model->getPublications();        
      $this->load->view('news_feed_view', $data);

}
```